# Failed to receive the Open Clip Art Library RSS feed

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape

I tried import drawings from OpenClipArt in my Ubuntu using Inkscape, but appear this problem below:

> Failed to receive the Open Clip Art Library RSS feed. Verify if the server name is correct in Configuration->Import/Export (e.g.: openclipart.org)

How can I fix this and import drawings from OpenClipArt.org?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because the default installed version of Inkscape on my Linux Mint 17.1 was very old (0.34 or something).  I downloaded the latest version (0.91) from https://inkscape.org/en/ and the problem has been fixed in that version.